# Get points inside a bounding box

Tags: php, pdo, postgis

I'm trying to choose places from my postgis db that are inside a certain bounding box. I'm trying to accomplish this with this query:

```
//latlong - latitude, longitude of a place

SELECT * FROM places WHERE St_Contains(St_GeomFromText('Polygon((:top_left_long :top_left_lat, :bottom_right_long :bottom_right_lat))'), latlong);
```

First of all - I get the following error:

```
 Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :top_left_lat
```

What does it mean? And the second issue - am I feeding these parameters in good order? I mean - first longitude, then latitude?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a query I used in an old project:

```
SELECT param1, param2, ... 
FROM messages 
WHERE ST_Contains( 
    ST_SetSRID(
        ST_MakeBox2D(
            ST_Point(0, 50), ST_Point(50,0)
        ), 
        4326
    ), 
    the_geom
)
```

the_geom was my geometry column
Note: MakeBox2D take top-left and right-bottom

Comment: The indentation kind of confused me. I was thinking why is `ST_SetSRID` taking `the_geom` as second param!?

Comment: And according to the [doc](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeBox2D.html), `ST_MakeBox2D(geometry pointLowLeft, geometry pointUpRight);` Low-left, top-right.

Answer (score 1):

With those arguments you can't build a *Polygon*.

A *Polygon* is a planar Surface defined by 1 exterior boundary and 0 or more interior boundaries. Each interior boundary defines a hole in the Polygon. A Triangle is a polygon with 3 distinct, non-collinear vertices and no interior boundary.

The exterior boundary LinearRing defines the “top” of the surface which is the side of the surface from which the exterior boundary appears to traverse the boundary in a counter clockwise direction. The interior LinearRings will have the opposite orientation, and appear as clockwise when viewed from the “top”.

The assertions for Polygons (the rules that define valid Polygons) are as follows:

a) Polygons are topologically closed;

b) The boundary of a Polygon consists of a set of LinearRings that make up its exterior and interior boundaries;

c) No two Rings in the boundary cross and the Rings in the boundary of a Polygon may intersect at a Point but
only as a tangent, e.g.

(taken from [OpenGIS Implementation Specification for Geographic information - Simple feature access - Part 1: Common architecture](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=25355))

With those arguments ou can either create a [box2d](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/box2d.html) or create the polygon feeding all the indidual points.

Two quick notes:

1. make sure your arguments are strings or `St_GeomFromText` will not work
2. use `ST_SetSRID` to define your coordinate system so that you don't have unpleasant results

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `:top_left_long` and other params are not replaced by your values.

Can you print the SQL query before the execution?

Comment: Actually those params are being replaced... But maybe you can suggest another query to accomplish this?